# onClick inside of a Modal

Tags: jestjs

Trying to figure out why simulate cant find node.
Trying to run a test click event inside of a Modal, but node can't be found
Using Jest / Enzyme for React JS

Here is how I set my state, System Entitlements being the class name.
Also did the following:

```
  beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter keyLength={0}><SystemEntitlements {...baseProps} /></MemoryRouter>));

  it("Test click event '", () => {
     baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
     wrapper.find('SystemEntitlements').setState({
       showSelectWarning:true,
       selectWarningModalOpen:false,   
       });
    console.log(wrapper.state())
    wrapper.find('SystemEntitlements').find('input[id="dontshow- testclick"]').simulate("click");
```

Console Log is returning NULL

Here is the file.js

```
 this.state.selectWarningModalOpen && 
 <Modal isOpen={this.state.selectWarningModalOpen} style={warningModalStyle}>
   <div>
     <div className='fullmodal'>
       <div className='sidemodal_addnew_x' onClick={this.closeModal}>
       <FontAwesome name='xbutton' className='fa-times' />
        </div>
        </div>   
          <div className='custom-ui'>
            <h1 className='confirm-entitlement-header'>Are you sure?</h1>
            <p className='confirm-entitlement-div'>This will update entitlements for this asset and may update the children of this asset</p>
            <div className='confirm-entitlement-div'>
             <div className='add-edit-button' id="closeModal-test-id" onClick={this.closeModal}>Cancel</div>
             <div className='add-edit-button' onClick={() => {
                this.handleChange(warningValue, warningRowIndex, warningColIndex, warningName)
                this.closeModal()
              }}>Continue</div>
           </div>
           <div className='confirm-entitlement-div'>
          <label>Do not show this message again</label>
            <input className='stop-message-checkbox' id='stop-message-checkbox' type='checkbox' checked={!this.state.showSelectWarning} onClick={() => {this.setState({showSelectWarning: !this.state.showSelectWarning})} } />
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: Could you show more code please? Also on your `console.log` can you try `wrapper.state().stateNameGoesHere` please and tell me result?

Comment: console log , i get null as aresult

Comment: Instead of `wrapper.find('SystemEntitlements').setState` can you try just `wrapper.setState`?

Comment: does not work, since im mounting it

Comment: @Corbuk any ideas ?

Comment: Can you show the the component `SystemEntitlements`? As that seems to be where the state is, correct?

Comment: its a big file, i would need to write on a codesandbox